# How to interpret this movie title: "Live is Life"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

There is a Netflix title: "Live is Life".

I can't wrap my head around it. Would that be something like:

1 - "to live means life"?

OR

2 - "energic is the life"?

Comment: Who can possibly tell what it means without context? Since with the verb _live_  /lɪv/ it makes no sense at all, I'd tend to interpret the first word as the adjective _live_  /laɪv/, and guess it might be talking about "live" as opposed to "rehearsed" or "recorded"; but it still doesn't mean much to me.

Comment: @Colin Fine, you are right without context is impossible to tell LOL!! but let me ask you one thing please: do you think there could be a context that satisfies the meaning of live be a verb and life the noun, like: to live is the definition of life"? rewrting that as "the life is to live"? do you think there could be a context that satisfies that idea?

Comment: I'll just note that a recent video game remake has a similarly confusing title: [Live a Live](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_A_Live). I've only seen it written and have no idea whether each "live" rhymes with "give" or "five".

Comment: What does it **sound** like? _Live_ is a noun, too, with a different pronunciation from the verb; it is often used in contrast with _recorded_ in reference to TV programs, for instance.

Comment: Everything's bloody alive these days. Where's the bug spray? In the UK there was (maybe still is) a mixed fruit drink (five different fruits) in cartons called 'Five Alive'.

Answer (score 4):

This film, release date July 18, 2022 (United States) is a 2021 Spanish language film directed by Dani de la Torre. It is a 'coming of age' drama/comedy about a boy returning from Catalonia (a part of Spain) to his parents' home in Galicia (another, distant, part of Spain) in 1985. He has been doing this every year but this time things are different, as real adult life is affecting him and the childhood gang of kids he used to run with. For one last vacation, the kids hunt down a magical flower that makes wishes come true.

The full title is 'Live is Life. La gran aventura'. The Spanish part means 'the big (or great) adventure'. The English words are taken from a 1984 Austrian pop music hit.

As the main title was created in 1984, and borrowed in 2021, by non-native-speakers, the intended meaning of the phrase, which is nonsensical in English, is a matter of guesswork. Possibly it is intended to convey something like 'Life is meant to be lived' or 'To have life one must live', etc. If 'live' is pronounced like the adjective (rhyming with 'hive') then perhaps it means 'life is about performing live' or 'life is about being in the immediate present'. Or it could mean *nothing at all*, like many pop music lyrics and titles.

Comment: nice thank you a lot. what you've said: "To have life one must live" that is similar to: "to live means life" by that I tried to convey: "life is to live" to do things to participate in life and not to be apart of that as in cases someone never do thing as take risks or make things happen. But let me please ask you something: as you've mentioned:  "To have life one must live" why that doesn't make sense in English when you self found sense?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho - "To have life one must _live_" makes sense if you emphasise 'live' and this would be understood to mean (as you note) to participate in life, take risks, make things happen, have love affairs, adventures, to travel, etc (to 'live life to the full').

Comment: can you please show an exemple of how to emphasise 'live'?

Comment: @Lynerapintcho - You can print it in italics, like I did above, or say the word in an emphasised way.

Comment: nice! thanks I unfortunately can't do the second option of say live in an emphasis way in this phrase

Comment: @Lynerapintcho - you could practise?

Comment: touché!! LOL!!!

Comment: +1 As soon as I saw the Q title I thought of that bloody awful pop song ;)) btw, for those who don't know it, the 'live' referred to is the one pronounced /laɪv/ rather than /lɪv/. Because of the paucity of the song lyric, it's impossible to tell whether they meant the adjective or adverb. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/live